# window.location troubling JQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I am trying to build a Progress Bar which on completion after a delay of 0.1 seconds ,hides the bar with a clip effect , then again after a delay of 0.2 seconds , the page loads google.com.

My code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Progressbar - Custom Label</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
  .ui-progressbar {
    position: relative;
  }
  .progress-label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var progressbar = $( "#progressbar" ),
      progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" );

    progressbar.progressbar({
      value: false,
      change: function() {
        progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
      },
      complete: function() {
        progressLabel.text( "Complete!" );
        $( "#progressbar" ).delay(100).hide("clip").delay(200);
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
      }
    });

    function progress() {
      var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;

      progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 3 );

      if ( val < 99 ) {
        setTimeout( progress, 100 );
      }

    }

    setTimeout( progress, 3000 );

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="progressbar"><div class="progress-label">Loading...</div></div>


</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that even before the effects can happen , the page loads http://www.google.com. Is there some sort of time delays which I can use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `setTimeout`

```
complete: function() {
        progressLabel.text( "Complete!" );
        $( "#progressbar" ).delay(100).hide("clip").delay(200);
       setTimeout(function() {

       window.location.href = "http://www.google.com" 

         }, 2000);
      }
```

So that it wait for 2 sec.

[Learn more about SetTimeOut](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Comment: Thanks.But , should I put this code just below`$( "#progressbar" ).delay(100).hide("clip").delay(200);` as it is ?

Comment: @GaurangTandon When you set the timeout ,The code inside the call back function executes after the delay you passed in the parameter

Comment: OK , this is working now . But why ,in my earlier code , the `window.location` got loaded before the effects had loaded even though I had given certain delays?

Comment: See while executing line by line,That is not asynchronous,You are not telling that wait until my delay ,finish.

Answer (score 1):

JAvascript is highly concurrent language... all the stuff basically happens simultaniously...

Right way to make things happend consequently is to wrap consequent code into anonymous functions..

```
(function(){
    //code executed first here
 })();

 (function(){
    //code executed second here
 })();
```

Or you could make custom wrapper methods and call them, executing location change as callback, when everything ends.

Comment: Nice , new knowledge gained.Thanks. But this is somewhat really tricky for me.